# Objective C - Loading content of a file but it shows null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a text file in Document directory. Then I wrote this code below to load the content of it.

```
NSURL *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                       inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                       appropriateForURL:nil
                       create:NO
                       error:nil];

NSURL *fullPath = [path URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];
NSLog(@"URL of text file is : %@", fullPath);
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Load the content of Text file : %@", content);
```

And I got `null` result like this:

```
2014-05-16 19:53:01.198 LoadStringContent[407:303] URL of text file is : file:///Users/Visal/Documents/text.txt
2014-05-16 19:53:01.199 LoadStringContent[407:303] Load the content of Text file : (null)
```

Anyone has any idea to correct it! Please help!

Thank!

Comment: Did you try seeing using the `error` parameter?

Comment: Does your file actually have Unicode encoded text? You're ignoring all helpful errors that the framework would return you.. try passing in a pointer to `NSError` to see the actual error

Comment: Is this really for iOS? An app's Document directory is not in the path you show.

Comment: Does the file exist *at that path*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

in

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fullPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
```

end check the error result.

Comment: Thank All! After re-created a text file and run again. This code worked just fine. So I guess I may did something wrong with the old one.